# Deploy list workflow on Client production server (using browser)

Tags: sharepoint-online, designer-workflow, deployment, production

I have created a list item workflow using SharePoint 2010 Workflow platform. Now I am trying to deploy my workflow in our clients production environment using browser.

Is it Possible using browser? How to achieve above task?

Answer (score 0):

after some research found artical[Understanding how to package and deploy workflow in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj819316%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

and [Deploying a workflow on a different server in SharePoint 2013](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/workflows_for_product_catalogs/archive/2012/11/02/deploying-a-workflow-on-a-different-server.aspx)

[Deploying a workflow on a different server in SharePoint 2013 - Workflows for Product Catalogs - Site Home](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/workflows_for_product_catalogs/archive/2012/11/02/deploying-a-workflow-on-a-different-server.aspx)    now its working for me

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the below link for detailed instructions to deploy the workflow using browser.

[Deploying List Workflow in SharePoint Online](http://sharepoint-works.blogspot.com/2016/10/deploying-list-workflow-in-sharepoint.html)

Hope this helps you!

Answer (score 0):

I just save the list as a template and import the template on the server. Then you can create a list from the imported template and you get the SP Designer workflows and custom item forms.